# jquerymobile 1.4.5 listview

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, mobile

I try to use listview , but it creates unwanted spaces.
How can i fix this problem.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a" data-cache="never">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Mail</li>
        <li> <a href="#">Inbox</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Outbox</a> </li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Contacts</li>
        <li> <a href="#">Friends</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Work</a> </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script>

Comment: Try removing the spaces/tabs in front of the LI elements in your markup and see if the problem goes away. If it does, you have some &nbsp; characters in your markup telling the browser to insert spaces...

Comment: Remove the following ";"
At the end here: <link rel="stylesheet" href="code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"; /> 
And here:<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">; </script> 

I did test your code, works allright in my Chrome Browser.
Have you made any css changes?